# Microphone input on W10 IoT Core

Tags: windows-10, iot

How can I enable the microphone input on Windows 10 IoT Core? I can't change it in the Device Portal. Does the mini-jack double as a mic input connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is no line-in on the Rpi but if you connect a USB headset you will see the slides in the device portal turn blue and then it will be a recognizable device in your code.

Additionally you could use a USB audio interface like it was done in this project: https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/speech-controlled-robot-49744c